# Как скопировать папку с помощью Premake5?

Tags: c++, build, project, project-management

**Вопрос №1**

Корневая папка выглядит примерно так:

```
<project-dir> 
├─build
│ └─bin
│   └─Debug
│     ├─data
│     │ └─player.png
│     └─game.exe
├─data
│ └─sprites
│   └─player.png
├─src
│ └─main.cpp
└─premake5.lua
```

При попытке скопировать папку `data` в папку `build/bin/Debug/` с помощью команды:

```
postbuildcommands "{COPYDIR} data \"build/bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}\" /s /h /e /k /f /c"
```

Вылазит вот такая ошибка:

```
error MSB3073: выход из команды "xcopy /Q /E /Y /I data "build\bin\Debug" \s \h \e \k \f \c
error MSB3073: :VCEnd" с кодом 4.
```

**Вопрос №2**

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Укажу путь напрямую из main.cpp (`loadFromFile("../data/sprites/player.png");`)
2. Укажу путь таким образом (`loadFromFile("data/sprites/player/png);`)

В первом варианте, код запускается в Visual Studio, но, если запустить `.exe`, то файл не будет найден, к тому же если исходный файл вложен много раз, придется писать `../../../` и т.д.

Во втором варианте, Visual Studio не может загрузить файл, но запускаемый `.exe` файл успешно его откроет.

Как можно избавиться от данной проблемы?